# How to properly move/read from a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, boost, shared-ptr

I have a caching system in one of my programs.  I have a single, static class that maintains this cache, and use the cache in multiple threads concurrently.  I am running into a problem maintaining the caching system correctly.  Here is some sample code.

```
class db_cache
{
    public:
        typdef std::map<int, int> map_t;

        static void update_cache();
        static boost::shared_ptr< const map_t > get_cache();

    private:
        db_cache();
        static void run_update();
        static boost::shared_ptr< const map_t > cur_cache_;
        static boost::shared_ptr< const map_t > old_cache_;
 };

 void db_cache::update_cache()
 {
     cur_cache_ = boost::make_shared< map_t >();
     old_cache_ = boost::make_sahred< map_t >();

     //   
     //Setup connection to server that sends updates
     //

     //Initialize cache
     run_update();
     while(true)
     {
         if(recv().compare("update") == 0)
         {
              //Update cache if update message recieved
              run_update();
         }
     }
}

void db_cache::run_update()
{
    //Create new cache to swap with current cache
    auto new_cache = boost:make_shared<map_t>();

    //
    //Put data in new cache
    //

    boost::atomic_store(&old_cache_, boost::move(cur_cache_));
    boost::atomic_store(&cur_cache_, boost::shared_ptr< const map_t >(boost::move(new_cache)));
}

auto db_cache::get_cache() -> boost::shared_ptr< const map_t >
{
    return boost::atomic_load(&cur_cache_);
}
```

I am currently getting a crash at `boost::atomic_store(&old_cache_, boost::move(cur_cache_));`.  The crash seems to be because `old_cache_` is null.  This seems to happen on the second time an update message is received.   I am assuming what is happening(not 100% sure, but the only one way I can think), is:

1. The first time the message is received, `cur_cache_` is copied to `old_cache_`.
2. `cur_cache_` is replaced with `new_cache`, causing the old `cur_cache_`(what `old_cache_` is currently pointing too) to be null.
3. `old_cache_` causes crash when `boost::atomic_store` is called again due to it being null.

My question is, why does the `boost::atomic_store(&old_cache_, boost::move(cur_cache_));` not cause the reference counter of `cur_cache_` to increase.  Is there a way I can make this happen?

Other note:

The reason I have `old_cache_` is because I believe I was having a problem when reading from the cache, which is most likely also a problem.  My program seemed to be crashing when trying to read elements from the map returned from `get_cache()`, so to make sure they stayed in scope until all threads that currently had a copy were done, I save the last version of the cache.  I suppose if I had the correct way to do this, I could get rid of the `old_cache_` all together, which should solve the problem above.

Edit:

Here is the code using the cache:

```
//Vector big, don't want to copy
const std::vector *selected_vec = &(*db_cache::get_cache()).at(get_string);
for( std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = selected_vec->begin(), e = selected_vec->end(); it != e; ++it)
{
   //String can be big, don't want to copy
   const std::string *cur_string = &(*it);
   if(cur_string == nullptr || cur_string->size() == 0)
   {
       continue;
   }
   char a = cur_string->at(0);  //Crash here

   //Do Stuff
}
```

My actual `map_t` type is a `std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>>` type not a `std::map<int,int>`.  After calling `get_cache()`, I get the vector I want, and iterator over the vector.  For each string, I try and get the first char.  When I try and get the char, the program crashes.  The only thing I can think of is that `selected_vec` is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a data race in `run_update`. The line that sets `old_cache_`:

```
boost::atomic_store(&old_cache_, boost::move(cur_cache_));
```

is performing a *non-atomic* modification to `cur_cache_`. Recall the signature of  `atomic_store`:

```
namespace boost {
template<class T>
void atomic_store( shared_ptr<T>* p, shared_ptr<T> r );
}
```

In passing the expression `boost::move(cur_cache_)` to that second parameter, your function creates the actual argument object by moving from `cur_cache_` and leaving it set to `nullptr`. Even if this modification *was* atomic, there's a window between this line and the later line that sets `cur_cache_` in which clients will see the `nullptr` returned from `get_cache`. If you absolutely want to preserve the value of `cur_cache_` in `old_cache_`, you need to use `atomic_exchange` to simultaneously set `cur_cache_` and retrieve the old value:

```
void db_cache::run_update()
{
    auto new_cache = boost:make_shared<map_t>();

    // ...

    auto old = boost::atomic_exchange(&cur_cache_, boost::move(new_cache));
    boost::atomic_store(&old_cache_, boost::move(old));
}
```

but it would appear that you have no use for `old_cache_` once the race is fixed, and you could eliminate it altogether:

```
void db_cache::run_update()
{
    auto new_cache = boost:make_shared<map_t>();

    // ...

    boost::atomic_store(
        &cur_cache_,
        boost::shared_ptr<const map_t>(boost::move(new_cache))
    );
}
```

The source of your original issue is in this "client" code:

```
const std::vector *selected_vec = &(*db_cache::get_cache()).at(get_string);
```

You store a pointer into the internals of an object accessed through a `shared_ptr`, but don't retain a reference to the object denoted by that `shared_ptr`. When you later dereference that pointer in the loop, it's possible that its referent has been destroyed. You need to keep a copy of the `shared_ptr` around to ensure that the referent stays alive while you use it (and you may as well use references instead of pointers):

```
boost::shared_ptr<const map_t> cache = db_cache::get_cache();
//Vector big, don't want to copy
const std::vector &selected_vec = cache->at(get_string);
for( std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = selected_vec->begin(), e = selected_vec->end(); it != e; ++it)
{
   //String can be big, don't want to copy
   const std::string &cur_string = *it;
   if(cur_string.size() == 0)
   {
       continue;
   }
   char a = cur_string.at(0);  //Don't crash here

   //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the `atomic_exchange` function. As for the second part, that was originally what I had, but I was running into a problem.   I will update the original post with some sample code of what my program is doing.   I guess my question is, is there any reason you can think of that the cache will be deleted before my threads using `cur_cache`, are finished running.  Should my `get_cache()` function not increase the use_count for the `shared_ptr` every time `get_cache()` is called?

Comment: @Eumcoz `get_cache` returns a copy of the `shared_ptr` which *does* increase  its `use_count`. The problem in the client code is that it drops that copy of the `shared_ptr` - decreasing the `use_count` - *before* it accesses the internals of the object the `shared_ptr` was pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I can put an answer for my crashing issue, although I still think there is a better way to design the solution.  Basically, my three step list was someone correct, `boost::atomic_store(&old_cache_, boost::move(cur_cache_));` was causing `cur_cache_` to have 0 references, and the object `cur_cache_` was pointing too was being freed.  The next time through the function, old_cache_ was then pointing too to the freed pointer, and it was causing a crash. My solution was to change

`boost::atomic_store(&old_cache_, boost::move(cur_cache_));`

to

`boost::atomic_store(&old_cache_, cur_cache_);`

which stopped `cur_cache_`'s use_count increase to two, after the first call, and go back down to 1 after the second call.

I still believe that there is a better way to structure my code without having to keep the `old_cache_`, and would be happy to accept an answer of someone who can explain that.